# angular2 rxjs Observable - supplied parameters do not meet signature of call target

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I've created the following component, following the Angular code example for constructing a new observable (https://angular.io/guide/observables#creating-observables).

I get an error on the line where I try to create the new Observable, as I've indicated in the code sample below. The error is 'supplied parameters do not meet signature of call target'

What have I missed?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-constructed-observable',
  templateUrl: './constructed-observable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./constructed-observable.component.css']
})
export class ConstructedObservableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  // error on Observable below 'supplied parameters do not meet signature of call target'
  const sequence = new Observable(sequenceSubscriber);

  function sequenceSubscriber(observer) {
    observer.next(1);
    observer.next(2);
    observer.next(3);
    observer.complete();

    return {unsubscribe() {}};
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sequence.subscribe({
      next(num) { console.log(num); },
      complete() { console.log('completed'); }
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: remove `function` keyword and change the sequence line to `sequence = new Observable(this.sequenceSubscriber);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sequence` is used in `ngOnInit` but not defined as class property.

**Fix. component.ts:**

```
 sequence: Observable<number>;

  constructor() {
    // error on Observable below 'supplied parameters do not meet signature of call target'
    this.sequence = new Observable(sequenceSubscriber);

    function sequenceSubscriber(observer) {
      observer.next(1);
      observer.next(2);
      observer.next(3);
      observer.complete();

      return { unsubscribe() { } };
    }
  }
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-observable-supplied-parameters-do-not-meet-signature)

Comment: Thanks Yerkon. This works on your StackBlitz but I get the same error using your code with Angular CLI 1.7.4, Angular Compiler 5.2.10 and RXJS 5.5.10

Comment: I realised that your code works. I no longer get the error on compiling but I still get the code marked as an error in VS Code with the same error message.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow, check your vsCode TypeScript version. It's should be the same as workspace `ts` version